# SQLite 3 размер типов данных в байтах

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть ли информация по объему типов данных СУБД SQLite (например, integer - 1 байт, real - ... и т.д). Не могу найти источник для подсчета объема моей бд в байтах, необходимо сложить все типы данных.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm

Comment: @MaxU Встречал этот источник, как я понял там указаны просто классы и типы данных, но размеры в байтах для каждого значения не указаны.

Comment: Больше чем [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), думаю, найти не получится...

Comment: @ArtemWelly да нету у SQLite никаких типов. Все данные хранятся строками.